# Php upload multiple images along with two input text field eg:email and folder name

Tags: javascript, php, html

PHP upload multiple images along with two input text field `eg:email` and folder name here is my code where I should add code that I could send multiple images along email and folder name:

```html
$max_size = 1024*1024*30; // 30mb
$extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
$dir = 'http://54.221.28.145:8080/kv_image_rest_service/rest/files/upload';
$count = 0;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    // loop all files
    foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name )
    {
        // if file not uploaded then skip it
        if ( !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) )
            continue;

        // skip large files
        if ( $_FILES['files']['size'][$i] >= $max_size )
            continue;

        // skip unprotected files
        if( !in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $extensions) )
            continue;

        // now we can move uploaded files
        if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $dir . $name) )
            $count++;
    }
}

echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));
```

Comment: it looks like it's already looping through all files which have been uploaded. What's your issue exactly?

Comment: i have form which have one field for email 2nd for folder name and 3rd for images upload ,so this code is only for images upload i want that i could send email and folder name as well to server along with images

Comment: read the values of `$_POST["email"]` and `$_POST["foldername"]` (assuming your HTML form elements have `name="email"` and `name="foldername"` attributes respectively)